# how to disable onbackpressed() for default video player called using Action_View intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am new to android and got a requirement to disable onbackpressed() for default video player. i am calling video player using intents as below

```
Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(path),"video/*");
startActivity(i);
```

Now i have to disable the back button for the video playing in default player(not the videoactivity) can any one please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am new to android and got a requirement to disable onbackpressed() for default video player.

That is not possible. The UI of the video player is determined by the developers of the video player, not you. This includes handing of the BACK button.

> Now i have to disable the back button until the video is finished

You will have to play back the video yourself, such as via `VideoView`.

You also should expect to have lots of negative reviews, and you should expect users to leave your app by other means to escape your video, such as pressing HOME, visiting the overview screen/recent tasks list, etc.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. may be i am out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

try this code ( You have to remove  `super.onBackPressed();`) to disable back button:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

    }
```

and when video is finished call `finish()`.

Comment: I had tried it in my activity but it is not working for the video but it is disabling the back button for the activity from which i am calling the video

Comment: Do this in your `videoactivity` not from calling activity.

Comment: sorry, but here i am not using videoactivity instead i am using intents to call the default player

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the video is finished via `OnCompletionListener`

`public class VideoPlayer extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener{`

when you will implement this, eclipse will add a new method "onCompletion" in your class:

`@Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        //video playback has ended, now do whatever you want to do.
    }`

after this set the `onCompletionListener` for your `videoview` like this:

`mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(VideoDisplayView.this);`

You can enable your back button in the `OnCompletion` method.
Good Luck!

Comment: if my question was unclear sorry for that but my main requirement is to disable the back button not checking the completion of video

Comment: @KRS yes I saw that and I did not respond to it because other people have answered your question but edit your question to be more clear because you are asking to disable it until the video is done which requires you to check if the video has finished. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this method....

---

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
         //super.onBackPressed();
//put your video playing condition here
     Intent setIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                                setIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                                setIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                startActivity(setIntent);
}
```